# How to mongorestore from the command line to a replicaset?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to perform a mongorestore command to a remote mongo replica set, to which I am connected via my workplace vpn.  My goal is to append the contents of a bson file to an existing collection.

I issue the following command from the windows shell, where I specify the replica-set connection string, the target database name (-d), the target collection name (-c) and the bson file (foo.bson).

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb://username:password@dd-domain-dev-shard-00-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-01-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-02-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017/?replicaSet=dd-domain-dev-shard-0" -d targetDatabase -c foo foo.bson
```

After 30 seconds, the following error appears.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my command, or how I can connect to this replica set?

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin>mongorestore --uri="mongodb://username:password@dd-domain-dev-shard-00-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-01-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-02-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017/?replicaSet=dd-domain-dev-shard-0" -d targetDatabase -c foo foo.bson

2020-12-24T21:46:19.383-0500    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout,

 current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [

 { Addr: dd-domain-dev-shard-00-01-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : connection(dd-domain-dev-shard-00-01-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017[-173]) incomplete read of message header: EOF },

 { Addr: dd-domain-dev-shard-00-02-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : connection(dd-domain-dev-shard-00-02-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017[-171]) incomplete read of message header: EOF },

 { Addr: dd-domain-dev-shard-00-00-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : connection(dd-domain-dev-shard-00-00-abc.azure.mongodb.net:27017[-172]) incomplete read of message header: EOF }, ] }
```

Comment: That looks like an Atlas connection string, doesn't that require --tls?

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine!

### MongoDB Enterprise version 4.4.17

(assuming replica set name = rs0)

```
mongorestore --host="rs0/node-1:27017,node-2:27017,node-3:27017" \
             --authenticationDatabase=admin \
             --ssl \
             --sslCAFile="/etc/mongodb/ssl/rootCA.pem" \
             --sslPEMKeyFile="/etc/mongodb/ssl/node-1.pem" \
             --tlsInsecure \
             -u admin \
             /path/to/your/backup
```